# Google chart Date format unable to Display

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

Iam using Google Chart to Show my sales Graph

In my chart in need to display the date wise sales

in X-axis the dates and Y Axis Amount

But in google chart, I can't able to print the date.
Below is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart(){
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('datetime', 'Time of Day');
         data.addColumn('number','Head Office');
             data.addColumn('number','Mohans Shoppy');
             data.addColumn('number','My shoppy');
                    data.addRows([
    [[new Date(2019,03,02)],2599,0,0],[[new Date(2019,03,03)],0,0,0],[[new Date(2019,03,04)],28625,0,15900],[[new Date(2019,03,05)],3934,0,0],[[new Date(2019,03,06)],0,0,0],[[new Date(2019,03,07)],3201,0,0],[[new Date(2019,03,09)],1500,0,0],          
    ]);
    var options = {
        title: 'Sales Chart',
        legend: { position: 'bottom' },
        width: 900,
        height: 500

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);   
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Iam getting the error in console: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Type mismatch. Value Tue Apr 02 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) does not match type datetime in column index 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[new Date(2019,03,02),2599,0,0],
[new Date(2019,03,03),0,0,0],
[new Date(2019,03,04),28625,0,15900],
[new Date(2019,03,05),3934,0,0],
[new Date(2019,03,06),0,0,0],
[new Date(2019,03,07),3201,0,0],
[new Date(2019,03,09),1500,0,0],
```

you added one extra [ ].

Comment: Thank you So much... It Works